# Android Null Pointer Exception when Creating Database

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sqlite

I have a sample app which creates a database, table and inserts a row of values.

Here is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final android.content.Context Context = null;
public String ReadingMode="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


             SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  Context.openOrCreateDatabase("WaterElectricityReading", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);

             sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                        "SampleTable " +
                        " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                        " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

             sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        "SampleTable " +
                        " Values ('Makam','sample','India',25);");

             sampleDB.close();                       
        }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

When I debug line by line, `Null pointer exception` is raised near the line:

```
 SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  Context.openOrCreateDatabase("WaterElectricityReading", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
```

I see that `sampleDB` is null and `Database` is not being created.

Is any thing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are initializing your Context with null

```
protected static final android.content.Context Context = null;
```

so when you are using your null Context , it will throw an NPE, you can Set your Context with your Activity Context and then use your Context

```
Context = MainActivity.this;
```

or just use this

```
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase("WaterElectricityReading", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing as `protected static final android.content.Context Context = null;`
and then using it as `Context.openOrCreateDatabase("WaterElectricityReading", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);`

It will produce null pointer exception for obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Repalce

```
  SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  Context.openOrCreateDatabase("WaterElectricityReading", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
```

with

```
  SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase("WaterElectricityReading", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
```

Reason :

1. `Activity` is subclass of `Context` so you can use `this`.
2. `openOrCreateDatabase` is not a static method so you cannot call it using class name.